# pgfplots \closedcycle command inside \foreach returning error

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, fillbetween

The following code demonstrates the problem. It builds fine, but if I add the commented `\closedcycle` command, it won't build (undefined control sequence).

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone} 
\usepackage{pgfmath}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\usepackage{calc}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\begin{document} 

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
      %title=title,
      %xlabel={xlabel},
      %ylabel={ylabel},
    ]
    \foreach \i/\j in 
      {
        1/red!0!blue,
        2/red!20!blue,
        3/red!40!blue,
        4/red!60!blue,
        5/red!80!blue,
        6/red!100!blue
      }{
      \edef\temp{\noexpand
        \addplot[
          color=\j,
          fill=\j,
          fill opacity=0.05
          ] 
          table 
          {expNum3D2\i1.dat};%\closedcycle;
      }
      \temp
    }
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Without `\closedcycle`, it looks like:
[image: without closedcycle]

However, I want the filling to be to the axis.

**additional inquiry**
I struggled to programmatically construct the array I'm looping over. I'd like to be able to set the number of plots `\n`, and create the array, including the color mixing from `blue` to `red`. Any help on this would also be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When using an expanded definition (`\edef`) for constructing the loop, you need to protect the commands that shouldn't be expanded, using `\noexpand` just like you did for the `\addplot` command. So instead of just using `\closedcycle`, you should use `\noexpand\closedcycle`.

However, for this application you don't even need to jump through all the `\edef` and `\noexpand` hoops: You can define the color list using the `cycle list` key and then use a "normal" `\foreach` loop:

```
\documentclass{standalone} 
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\begin{document} 

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
      cycle list={
        red!0!blue, fill=red!0!blue\\
        red!20!blue, fill=red!20!blue\\
        red!40!blue, fill=red!40!blue\\
        red!60!blue, fill=red!60!blue\\
        red!80!blue, fill=red!80!blue\\
        red!100!blue, fill=red!100!blue\\
      }
    ]
    \foreach \i in 
      {1,...,6}{
      \addplot +[fill opacity=0.05] 
          {cos(deg(x/3))+rand/5+\i/5} \closedcycle;
    }
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

---

To answer your second question: You can use a colormap, which linearly interpolates between two (or more) colors. To fill between the plot and the axis without drawing the border, you can use the `fillbetween` library:

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone} 
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{data1.dat}
0 0.6
1 2.2
\end{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{data2.dat}
0 0.4
1 1.8
\end{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{data3.dat}
0 0.2
1 1.4
\end{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{data4.dat}
0 0
1 1
\end{filecontents}



\begin{document} 
\def\numberOfPlots{4}
\pgfplotsset{
/pgfplots/colormap={bluered}{color=(blue) color=(red)}
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}
  \addplot [draw=none, name path=axis, domain=0:1] {0};
    \pgfplotsinvokeforeach{1,...,\numberOfPlots}{
      \pgfplotscolormapfind[1:\numberOfPlots]{#1}{bluered}
      \definecolor{mycolor#1}{rgb}{\pgfmathresult}
      \addplot [draw=mycolor#1, name path=plot#1] table {data#1.dat};
      \addplot [mycolor#1, fill opacity=0.2] fill between[of=plot#1 and axis];
    }
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you, @Jake, this is really informative. Would you mind answering a couple minor follow-ups?
(1) I have learned how to make my own `cycle list` macro, but I haven't figured out how to set the total number of plots (six was an example) and shift my color from red to blue based on that.
(2) `\closedcycle` is great, but I'd prefer the same fill *without* closing the line. Is that possible?

Comment: Solved (2) by doing successive plots, one with `draw=none`, the other with `fill=none`. (1) is still a problem for me.

Comment: @RicoPicone: I've edited my answer

Comment: Jake, this is very nice, thank you. The only issue is that I'd like to wrap this `axis` call in a `def` so that I can make multiple calls to it for different `ymin`, `ymax`, `xlabel`, etc. Then I run into the scoping problems I've been reading about with `\pgfplotsinvokeforeach`. Any advice?